# retrieve data from database using session

Tags: php, session, fetch

Hi I had read topics here and tried doing it in different ways but my problem still not solved. I tried storing session and use it to retrieve data again from the database. I used the session idmember and set it to a variable then used it to a query to echo his/her first and last name. I can get to the main page but the user's name doesn't echo it. 
To summarize here how it works. index > authenticate(validate) > student/index.php

functions.php

```
<?php 

function sec_session_start() {
        $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
        $secure = true; // Set to true if using https.
        $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
        session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
        session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
        session_start(); // Start the php session
        session_regenerate_id(); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.     
}



?>
```

index.php (Main Page)

```
<?php 
include ('include/functions.php');
sec_session_start();
include ('header.php');
?>
<title>Students Portal</title>
<div id="upper_row"><b>Announcement:</b></div>
    <div id="l_column"></div>

      <div id="r_column">
      <form action="authenticate.php" method="POST" name="loginform">
  <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3" align="left">USER LOGIN<br /><hr /></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="72">Username:</td>
        <td width="212">
             <script type="text/javascript">
            function blank(a) { if(a.value == a.defaultValue) a.value = ""; }
            function unblank(a) { if(a.value == "") a.value = a.defaultValue; }
            </script> 
        <input type="text" value="Enter your School ID here" onfocus="blank(this)" onblur="unblank(this)" name="id" />
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Password:</td>
         <td><script type="text/javascript">
        function blank(a) { if(a.value == a.defaultValue) a.value = ""; }
        function unblank(a) { if(a.value == "") a.value = a.defaultValue; }
        </script> 
        <input type="password" value="Password" onfocus="blank(this)" onblur="unblank(this)" name="password" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      <td rowspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" /></td>
      </tr>
  </table>

      </form>
      </div>


  <?php 
include "footer.php";
?>
```

authenticate.php

```
<?php
include ('include/conn.php');
include ('include/functions.php');
sec_session_start();
// username and password sent from form
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {    
        $user=$_POST['id'];
        $pass=$_POST['password'];

        // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
        $user = stripslashes($user);
        $pass = stripslashes($pass);
        $user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
        $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
        $crypt_pass=md5($pass);
        //query from database
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT username,user_pass,user_id FROM tbl_user WHERE username ='$user' and user_pass='$crypt_pass'");
        $result2=mysql_fetch_row($result);
        // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

        //First Step of Validation
        //get the ip address of the user then the attempts
        $iptocheck = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $iptocheck = mysql_real_escape_string($iptocheck);
        $resultip = mysql_query("SELECT ip_address,login_attempts,username FROM tbl_sec_login WHERE ip_address = '$iptocheck' AND username='$user'");
        $ipcount = mysql_num_rows($resultip);
        $rowx = mysql_fetch_row($resultip);

        if(mysql_num_rows($resultip) > 1) {
            //Already has some IP address records in the database
            //Get the total failed login attempts associated with this IP address
            if ($rowx['1'] > 3) {
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
        }
        //If none then insert it to the table
        else if ($ipcount == 0) {
            $loginattempts = 0;

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_sec_login (ip_address,login_attempts,username) VALUES ('$iptocheck','$loginattempts','$user')");
        }
        //Second step of validation
        //if count is equal to 1 then proceed to next condition
        if($count==1){
                //Third Step of Validation
                // If result matched $user and $crypt_pass, table row must be 1 row

                if ($user==$result2[0] AND $crypt_pass==$result2[1]){
                    $_SESSION['idmember'] = $_POST['id'];

                    $loginattempts = 0;
                    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_sec_login WHERE ip_address = '$iptocheck' AND username='$user'");


                    if($result2[2]==3) {
                    header("Location: student/index.php?id=$user");
                    }elseif ($result2[2]==2) {
                    header("Location: epersonnel/index.php");
                    }elseif ($result2[2]==1) {
                    header("Location: admin/index.php");
                    }

                }else{
                    $loginattempts = $rowx['1'] + 1;

                    mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_sec_login SET login_attempts = '$loginattempts' WHERE ip_address = '$iptocheck' AND username='$user'");
                    header("Location: login.php");
                }

            } 
            else {
                $loginattempts = $rowx['1'] + 1;

                mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_sec_login SET login_attempts = '$loginattempts' WHERE ip_address = '$iptocheck' AND username='$user'");
                header("Location: login.php");
            }
        }

        else {
            header("Location: index.php");
            }


?>
```

---

student/index.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 

if(!empty($_SESSION['idmember'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
}
require 'include/conn.php';
$id = $_SESSION['idmember'];
$query="SELECT first_name,last_name FROM tbl_studentmasterlist WHERE sid ='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

include "header.php";
?>
<div id="s_l_column">
    <div id="i_location">
    Welcome, <br />
    <center><img name="" src="" width="185" height="135" alt=""> <br />
    &raquo; <?php echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'];?> </center>
    <hr />
    </div>

    <div id="side_menubar">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="s_r_column">

    <div class="menubar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="leftEdge clearBorder">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Account Setting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enrollment Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enroll</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="rightEdge">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>                
    </div>

    <div id="b_contianer">

    </div>

</div>


<?php 
include "footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: I tried using $_GET using for example www.test.php?cn=
but the thing is that i figured it out that it become public to everyone to see. any suggestions?
and answers from the above? coz i think session is the only way it is.

Comment: just edited it. here it goes i tried doing isset function but is seems my session is not set even if i tried to set it in the validation process after is successful. I'm using a 5.0.51 mysql just it case it my codes just affects the version.

Comment: Please be warned that your queries are highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked. Also, `md5` is not a suitable algorithm for passwords, and removing slashes from a password and escaping it before hashing is is completely useless

Answer (score 0):

Why do you redirect to the login.php page, when you already have set the $_SESSION['idmember'] variable? That doesn't make much sense.

Your code does the following:

When you call the index.php site the first time your session variable 'idmember' isn't set and thus the first and last name isn't displayed, because your query doesn't return any results.

The problem here lies in the following lines of code (index.php):

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['idmember'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Here you check, if your session variable 'idmember' is NOT empty. So, every time you call index.php with 'idmember' set you will be redirected to login.php.

To fix this just replace your code with the following one:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['idmember'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

This checks, if the session variable 'idmember' is NOT set and redirects the user to the login.php page, if it is so. After the user logged in successfully, and the user calls index.php again your query will return a result (provided that a user with the 'idmember' value actually exists...). And finally, the first and last name should be displayed.

Comment: I tried doing that also but it does really redirects me to login.php
and it seems that the session was not set even if i already tried setting it in the authenticate.php. Is it anything to do with the version of my mysql coz i'm using the older version of Mysql 5.0.51 .
but i'm still looking for the solution not thinking of the version coz it does not anything to do with it right?

Comment: Yes, it's not a problem to use an older version of MySQL.

Why do you call in student/index.php the function session_start and not your defined function sec_session_start?

Comment: Oh that one. I tried using my function call sec_session_start too but when i login it redirects me to my login.php when supposedly it will redirect me to student/index.php successfully unless it does not set the session the one I assigned from authenticate.php

Comment: Have you tried to 'trace' the code with echo-statements?

Please insert an `echo $count;` in authenticate.php before `if($count==1){`. This shows you, if the query returned any data rows.

Comment: sorry for the late reply I have fixed my problem by storing session(s)
without using class. Because I used a class to make it secured but i think i only got a problem so what I did store it. Thanks for your answers.